# Specify the contentType in Amazon Lambda function output based on the contentType of incoming request?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am working on `Amazon` `Lex` `bot` and in my `python` `Lambda` function I have the following as the output return:

```
    def close(session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }
    }

    return response

def Test_Bot(intent_request):
    # bunch of other code processing

    # call to close() in final output return
    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Thanks for asking!'
        }
    )
```

Here is how my input to the `Lambda` function looks like:

```
def dispatch(intent_request):

    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']

    # Dispatch to your bot's intent handlers
    if intent_name == 'TestBot':
        return Test_Bot(intent_request)


    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')


# --- Main handler ---


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return dispatch(event)
```

**Note** this is not the full code but a part of the input and output code.

Now the problem that I am facing is that my code works perfectly fine from start to end if I `type-in` my question through the `Lex` test bot console. But if I `speak-in` my questions then the code breaks breaks at the end point. Now if I am correct its because the `contentType` is set as `PlainText` so when I `type-in` the questions it works fine but when I am `speak-in` the questions then it is expecting `audio` in `contentType` which is not there and so it breaks.

So my question is how can I access the `contentType` of the incoming request? Means if the user is typing then the `contentType` in above response format be set to `PlainText` and when user is speaking in then `contentType` be set to `audio`?

Comment: Has your bot been configured with Voice output? In the console, check under settings > Output voice

Answer (score 0):

By making a bot communicating straight from Lex to Lambda, you can’t change the value of ‘outputDialogMode’, it has to be done outside by invoking Lex with an accept header of text or audio. In practical terms this means you can’t use PostContent responses.

I also faced this situation and the workaround I found was to create an audio file with Polly on the fly, then store it in S3, and then reference the saved file in attachmentLinkUrl field of a response card.

See the `sing_a_song` method [in this example.](https://github.com/imTachu/ShakiraChatbot/blob/master/chatbot/botcontrol.py)